# NuGet CLI not restore the package for the packagereference

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore, packagereference

I have created a new .net core project with Visual Studio 2017, then add a nuget package `Newtonsoft.Json` to the project. After that I know the package will cached at the folder `C:\Users\<UserName>\.nuget\packages`.

For some reason, I have to delete it, then I want to restore it, **but** I could not restore it with nuget.exe. `nuget.exe restore`, command can be executed successfully, but the package is not downloaded to that folder.

I also have tried the command `MSBuild /t:restore`, but it still does not work, package not download.

Any suggestion?

Comment: what version of nuget.exe do you use ?

Comment: @D.J., The nuget version is 4.7.0.5148.

Comment: Some issues with nuget restoring/building took me to manually clean */obj directories. Nuget wants to work with project.assets.json there, which can be bad for some reason.